# PhoneGap beginner issue with launching an sample app

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, cordova

I started with PhoneGap in Eclipse and made a basic app with some basic paragraph text...and it works fine in my emulator and real device (android os) ...but now I tried with some sample projects for the the PhoneGap 2.x Mobile Application Dev. Hotspot - from here

https://github.com/photokandyStudios/PhoneGap-HotShot-Book-Code-Bundle

and when I run the projects in my emulator or real devices it comes to 'Connecting to device' splashscreen and it never ends.

The same thing happened with the demo example coming in phonegap - only the splashscreen says "Device is ready".

[image: phone gap]

Answer (score 0):

I just want to note that I resolved the issue. Namely it was related to the github repo folder organization...just copy/paste the chapterXX/www folder to chapterXX/android/assets folder...it works then fine